# How to Sinon spy a Vue component method triggered by a Vue event?

Tags: vuejs2, sinon

The basic setup that I've done in order to describe my problem:

Using vue-cli 2.8.2, I generated a new project based on webpack template (`vue init webpack vue-test-sinon-spy`) keeping all the defaults of vue-cli (with the irrelevant exception of disabling eslint).

Changes done in this vue-cli generated project:

1. I attached an event on h2 tag from Hello.vue:

```html
<h2 @click="sayHello">Essential Links</h2>
```

2. I added a method in Hello component

```html
<script>
export default {
  ...
  methods: {
    sayHello() {
      console.log('hello!')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

3. I added a new test in Hello.spec.js

```js
describe('Hello.vue', () => {
  // ...

  it('should handle click on h2 tag', () => {
    const Constructor = Vue.extend(Hello)
    const vm = new Constructor().$mount()
    sinon.spy(vm, 'sayHello')

    // [A] if I run the line below, vm.sayHello.callCount will be 0 - not as expected
    vm.$el.querySelector('h2').click()

    // [B] if I run the line below, vm.sayHello.callCount will be 1 - as expected
    // vm.sayHello()

    // vm.sayHello.callCount will be 0 or 1, depending on
    //    what line I execute ([A] or [B]),
    //    even if in both cases sayHello method is really executed
    console.log('###', vm.sayHello.callCount)
  })
})
```

When I programmatically click the html tag (using `vm.$el.querySelector('h2').click()`), spy won't capture the execution of the method `sayHello`, thus `vm.sayHello.callCount` will be 0. Not what I like.

But, if I directly call `sayHello` (using `vm.sayHello()`), `vm.sayHello.callCount` will be 1. As I expect.

How can I make spy capture the call of `sayHello` (so that `vm.sayHello.callCount` will be 1), if I want to simulate the click on the html tag (`vm.$el.querySelector('h2').click()`), and not directly calling `sayHello` (no `vm.sayHello()`)?

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't this make a better e2e test? I don't think unit tests should be concerned with UI interactions

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem here is that callback is being bound to the event when the component is mounted. I'm not sure exactly how it works in the background but it's like its a copy of the `sayHello` method within the click event scope. You can't modify it after it has been bound.

You are creating the spy after that on the components method. They act the same but they are not. One is a spy and one is not.

`wrapper.vm.sayHello()` executes the method (spied on)
`wrapper.find('h2').trigger('click')` executes the callback (not spied on)

Create the spy on the component Class before mounting rather than the instance afterwards and it should work as expected.

```
it('should handle click on h2 tag - vue-test-utils + dummy click version', () =>     {
    const clickSpy = sinon.spy(Hello.methods, 'sayHello')
    const wrapper = mount(Hello)
    ...
})
```

Comment: can we do the same for data variable also? something like: sinon.spy(Hello.data, 'datavariable') ?

Comment: No. Spies are only used to monitor a function or an object method.
https://abdulapopoola.com/2016/04/11/how-function-spies-work-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

(Note [Phil's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45787562/how-to-sinon-spy-a-vue-component-method-triggered-by-a-vue-event?noredirect=1#comment78533937_45787562) on this not being a valid use of unit tests.)

A workaround that I found is this:

1. Install [vue-test-utils](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils): `yarn add --dev https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils` (afaiu, vue-test-utils is [not officially released](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/ava-with-vue-test-utils/14086/5) yet)
2. Trigger a dummy click event

Now, you can add a new test, which will run as expected:

```js
describe('Hello.vue', () => {
  // ...
  it('should handle click on h2 tag - vue-test-utils + dummy click version', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(Hello)
    sinon.spy(wrapper.vm, 'sayHello')

    // trigger a dummy click event
    wrapper.find('h1').trigger('click')

    // [A] if I run the line below, vm.sayHello.callCount will be 1 - as expected
    wrapper.find('h2').trigger('click')

    // [B] if I run the line below, vm.sayHello.callCount will be 1 - as expected
    // wrapper.vm.sayHello()

    // vm.sayHello.callCount will be 1 in both [A] and [B] cases
    console.log('#####', wrapper.vm.sayHello.callCount)
  })
})
```

This behavior is so weird and make Vue looks more like a pet project than like a 2.x.x project, that maybe I misunderstood something.